# define startup image and icon in Sencha ExtJS modern

Tags: javascript, extjs, touch, extjs6, extjs6-modern

Back when Sencha had Sencha Touch (2.4) you could set startupImage and icon to define images for startup the app icon for your app.

Currenctly I'm moving from Touch to ExtJS (6 modern toolkit) and this doesn't seem to exists anymore. Also in the changelog and forums I can't seem to find the answer. Does anyone here know something to get app loader images defined and an app icon?

I do not use Cordova, it'll be a normal webapp. When putting the app on your homescreen on both iOS and Android the defined icon will be shown and when starting the app from the homescreen, the app would use the defined splash screen(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Sencha introduces this, it was a specialty for iOS. Sencha anticipated wide adoption of similar features by other mobile browsers. Instead, Apple started running havoc with special parameters, Google and/or Mozilla invented a JSON manifest that cannot be created by Javascript code, and since ExtJS already was always lagging behind with these features, the code overhead was overkill, and support was dropped (at least for now).

You should look into [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html), [Android documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen) and/or [generalized information](http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/adding-an-icon-for-iphone-ipad-android-to-your-website/) how to add the icon and startup image to your application's `index.html` file using meta tags, and/or how to write manifest files.

Comment: Ahh perfect! That will definitely help me to develop what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are using Cordova to package your app. So, you can use "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" to define the startup image.

As for the icon, put it directly in the platform project generated by Cordova. For example, for Android platform, put the icon image in "cordova\platforms\android\res\drawable-*" folders.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I do not use Cordova, it's just a webapp.I will change this in my original question.